# Remove duplicates from array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Input: `int arr[] = {10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50}`

Output: `10, 30`

My code:

```
int removeDup(int arr[], int n)
{
    int temp;
    bool dupFound = false;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                if(!dupFound){
                    temp = arr[i];
                    dupFound = true;
                }
                else{
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //shift here
}
```

First of all, I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this.

I'm trying to find the first duplicate element, assign it to every duplicate element and shift them to the end of the array, which doesn't work because the last duplicate element cannot be compared.

I need some help with finding the last duplicate element, so I can assign `temp` to it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, but wouldn't `std::unique()` output `10,20,30,40,50` ?

Comment: What does "assign it to every duplicate element" mean? Why is the desired output 10,30? This is clearly something different than removing duplicate elements..

Comment: @Botje like assume the first duplicate item is 20. The second duplicate item is 40. My idea is to assign 20 to the second duplicate, so they all are equal to 20. And then shift all 20's to the end...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've included the desired input/output

Comment: How is 30 a "second duplicate item"? There's only one instance of it.. And why are you "shifting things to the end" if the end result is a two-element array?

Comment: @Botje Well the shifting isn't really needed. I could just check if the element is `!=temp`. The 7 other elements don't go anywhere. I just need help with replacing the last elements of each duplicate with `temp`.

Comment: The sample input you show is sorted. Do you expect the input to always be sorted? If not, are you allowed to produce the output in sorted order, even if the input isn't? It's simple to process the data efficiently if it's sorted.

Comment: What is the point of trying to replacing the duplicates with temp? `arr[j] == arr[i]`, therefore it must also be equal to `temp` (which came from `arr[i]` initially)

Comment: @Botje well so I can tell which items are unique and which aren't. I can't just assign a random number and hope it is not in the array, And why must `arr[i]` be equal to temp?

Comment: you should not bother about efficiency when your current code does not produce correct output. Not removing any elements is more efficient than your current code, and just as correct ;)

Comment: @JerryCoffin no elements dont have to be sorted, but can be sorted.

Comment: Because you literally set `temp=arr[i]` when you saw the _first_ duplicate and when `arr[j] == arr[i]`, you try to overwrite `arr[i]` with temp! Even if you meant `arr[j]` there, you're still overwriting a value with the same number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do everything at once, let us focus on correctness first:

```
int removeDup(int* arr, int n) {
  // Note: No i++! This depends on whether we find a duplicate.
  for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
    int v = arr[i];
    bool dupFound = false;

    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
      if (v == arr[j]) {
        dupFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!dupFound) {
      i++;
      continue;
    }

    // Copy values to the sub-array starting at position i,
    // skipping all values equal to v. 
    int write = i, skipped = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
      if (arr[j] != v) {
        arr[write] = arr[j];
        write++;
      } else {
        skipped++;
      }
    }

    // The previous loop duplicated some non-v elements.
    // We decrease n to make sure these duplicates are not
    // considered in the output
    n -= skipped;
  }

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand the logic of your code. When you find the second element `arr[j]` that equals `arr[i]` you will assign `temp` to `arr[i]`. However, `temp` has been assigned `arr[i]` when you found the first duplicate. Essentially you do `arr[i] = arr[i]`. Its not clear how this is supposed to find unique elements.

You can use a map to count frequency of elements, then print those with frequency 1:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,size_t> freq;
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50};
   
    // count frequencies 
    for (auto e : arr) { ++freq[e]; }

    // print the elements e where freq[e] == 1
    for (const auto& f : freq) {
        if (f.second == 1) {
            std::cout << f.first << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Only small modifications needed to add the unique elements to a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with logistics (so to speak). An array always contains a fixed number of items. There's simply no way to start with an array of 5 items, and turn it into an array of 2 items. Simply can't be done.

So, as a starting point, you need to either return something like an `std::vector` that keeps track of its size along with the data it contains, or else you're going to need to track the size, and return something to indicate how many elements in the array are valid after the processing.

Probably the simplest way to do things would be to use something like an `std::unoredered_map` to count the items, then walk through the map, and insert an item in the output if (and only if) its count is 1.

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> counts;
for (int i=0;i<n; i++)
    ++counts[arr[i]];

std::vector<int> output;
for (auto item : counts)
    if (item.second == 1)
        output.push_back(item.first);
return output;
```

If you want to modify the data in place, I'd start by sorting the input data. Then you'll start with two indices: one for your "input" position, and one for your "output" position. `output` starts as zero, and `input` as 1.

The general idea from there is pretty simple: we look at `data[input]` and see if it's different from both the preceding and succeeding elements. If so, we copy it to `data[output]`, and increment the output position.

Since this tries to look at both the preceding and succeeding elements, we have to include special cases for the beginning and end of the array. The first element is unique if it's different from the following, and the end is unique if it's different from the preceding. Code can look like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

unsigned remove_dupe(int *data, unsigned n) { 

    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }

    std::sort(data, data+n);

    unsigned output = data[0] != data[1];

    for (unsigned input = output+1; input<n-1; input++)
        if (data[input] != data[input-1] && data[input] != data[input+1])
            data[output++] = data[input];
    if (data[n-1] != data[n-2]) {
        data[output++] = data[n-1];
    }

    return output;
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
void test(T (&arr)[N]) {
    unsigned end = remove_dupe(arr, N);

    for (int i=0; i<end; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    int arr0[] = {10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50};
    int arr1[] = { 1, 2};
    int arr2[] = { 1, 1};

    test(arr0);
    test(arr1);
    test(arr2);
}
```

Result:

```
10  30  
1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might be available is to `sort()` the array.  When this is done, *all* duplicate values throughout the array are now ***adjacent.***  You simply compare element `[n]` with element `[n+1]` to see if they are the same. You can now find and count *all* duplicates in a single linear pass through the sorted array.

Sorting is one of the most heavily-studied class of algorithms in computer science, and very efficient processes can be developed which rely upon things being sorted a certain way.